# OAuth::Unauthorized 400 error with Google+ login API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, google-api, omniauth

I'm trying to set up Google+ login with Devise and omniauth in an app I'm working on and running into an OAuth::Unauthorized 400 error. I'm using the omniauth-google gem. My Devise config sets up omniauth for Google:

```
config.omniauth :google, ENV['GOOGLE_KEY'], ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET'], scope: 'plus.login'
```

I'm running the site locally on dev.app.com:3000, and in my app settings in the Google Developers Console I've set the JavaScript origin to be http://dev.app.com:3000 and the redirect URI to be http://dev.app.com:3000/users/auth/google/callback. I've confirmed that my key and secret are correct. What's the problem here?

Comment: are u using `omniauth-google` gem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not seeing any problem there, you can get better picture with this tutorial 
[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-devise-and-omniauth-for-your-rails-application

or u can try

omniauth-google-oauth2

https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2

Comment: Thanks, I got it working using the omniauth-google-oauth2 gem and changing the provider to be `:google_oauth2` in all parts of my code.

Answer (score 0):

The omniauth-google 1.0 strategy for google is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref). That said, nothing appears wrong with your configuration.

You're better of switching to [OAuth 2.0](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2), unless you have a very compelling reason not to. Notice that the provider symbol has changed from `:google` to `:google_oauth2`. After you switch, it should look like:

```
provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_KEY"], ENV["GOOGLE_SECRET"]
```