# "OAuth::Unauthorized" error when tryihng to get Google authentication to work with Rails "devise" gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, google-authentication

I’m using Rails 4.2.5 and I’m trying to enable authentication through Google to allow access to my application.  I’m following the https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-devise-and-omniauth-for-your-rails-application'>devise tutorial.  I have added these gems

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-digitalocean'
gem 'omniauth-google'
```

and likewise followed the other steps in the tutorial including adding google as an OAuth provider into my devise config in the config/initializers/devise.rb file …

```
    config.omniauth :google, “myclientid”, “myclientsecret”
```

When I start and run my Rails server, I can see my sign up page at

http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in

and when I click “Sign in with Google”, which points at this URL — http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google, I get this error …

```
OAuth::Unauthorized
400 Bad Request

Extracted source (around line #216): 

    self.token_request(http_method, uri.path, token, request_options, arguments)
  when (400..499)
    raise OAuth::Unauthorized, response
  else
    response.error!
  end
```

Anyone have any idea what I have overlooked?

Comment: have you got a solution for this , I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314060/oauthunauthorized-400-error-with-google-login-api) worked for me.

Change from omniauth-google to omniauth-google-oauth2